# How can i get value from SQL functions on c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I have a c# project. I want get return value of sql function. My sql function is:

```sql
CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[EnPahaliYemek]( @yemekk varchar(10))
RETURNS varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @yemek varchar(50)
    SET @yemek=(SELECT TOP 1 mealPrice FROM meal ORDER BY mealPrice DESC)
    RETURN @yemek
END
```

I want call this function in my project and keep return value(@yemek) in a variable. How can I do this?

I tried this.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=true;");
SqlCommand cmd =new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;

cmd.CommandText = "dbo.(EnPahaliYemek)";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@yemek", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@yemek"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;


con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
label1.Text = cmd.Parameters["@yemek"].Value.ToString();
con.Close();
```

I am expecting label1.Text to have the value of the output parameter, but it is instead the empty string.

Comment: Before post this question did search smt?

Comment: i edited.please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL function returns a scalar value, you should use the [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.  That returns an object, so don't forget to cast it to the appropriate type.

```
var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=true;");
var cmd =new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "select dbo.[EnPahaliYemek](@yemekk);";    
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yemekk", "whatever");

con.Open();
label1.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
con.Close();
```